# Protect a vue route with multiple guards

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue router like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

function guard (to, from, next) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/login')
  }
}

function admin (to, from, next) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('admin') && localStorage.getItem('admin') !== 'false' && localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/noadmin')
  }
}

export default new Router({

  mode: 'history',

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      beforeEnter: guard,
      meta: { layout: 'default' },
      component: () => import('@/components/dashboard.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/datacollector',
      name: 'datacollector',
      beforeEnter: guard,
      meta: { layout: 'default' },
      component: () => import('@/components/datacollector.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/licensing',
      beforeEnter: admin,
      name: 'licensing',
      component: () => import('@/components/licensing.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      component: require('@/pages/404.vue').default
    }
  ]

})
```

My problem now is the following, if there is an entry `localStorage.getItem('datacollector')` it should only point to the path `/datacollector` and `/logout`. So when he logs in, the login page throws him to the path `/datacollector`. But he should also be able to call `logout`. For the other users, it should be that they are allowed to call everything. How do I adjust the function `guard`, no matter what I try I always end up with a loop. Thank you.

Comment: Where is your **/login** and **/noadmin** path in your router? Both will bring you to the **404** page... Can you try also to replace **path:' * '** to  **path: '/:catchAll(.*)*'**

Comment: It is there I removed it from the code above so it will not overblow here everything

Comment: Nice, to you have a **beforeEnter** there also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to throw the user to `/datacollector` route from any route, if there is an entry for `localStorage.getItem('datacollector')`, except for `/logout` route.

You can simply check for `to.path` and redirect the user accordingly:

```js
function guard (to, from, next) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('jwt')) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('datacollector')) {
      if (to.path != '/datacollector' && to.path != '/logout'){
        next('/datacollector');
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next('/login')
  }
}
```